# Read an XML file and store as an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlreader

I am new to C#, MVC4, ASP.NET, Entity Framework.

I have an XML file which I want to convert to a c# object.

How do I do this?

To give an idea of what I would like to do with the XML file:
I wish to display certain parts of the xml file within a table in a view.
I wish to be able to select parts of the data and send to a database.

At present, I have...

```
        public ViewResult Index()
    {
        string url = "......";
        var xml = XDocument.Load(url);

        return View(xml);
    }
```

My view model is:
    @model IEnumerable
But I get an error on run saying:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]'.

Comment: Take a look at this.. Read in the file, and do with it whatever you want... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Comment: As a first attempt: `View(xml.Root.Elements())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different methods of dealing with XML in .NET.  These include [XML Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), which will turn an XML string into a properly designed object; using [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333), which allows you to designate by a series of node names the information you want; or using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), which allows you to read through and parse the XML.

**EDIT:** Going with [Xlinq](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/05/26/safe-x-ml-parsing-with-xlinq-xlinqextensions-helps-make-xml-parsing-with-net-s-xlinq-a-bit-safer-and-easier.aspx), you'd want to pass as a model either `XElement` or `IEnumerable<XElement>` to the view

```
@model XElement
```

or

```
@model IEnumerable<XElement>
```

Comment: Yup, there are other methods available, I just listed a few.

Comment: Yes, but XLINQ is by far the easiest.  XmlReader is not simple.

Comment: So what is the best way (performance wise) to turn the XML doc into object? And why did somebody downrate my post when it seems like a good question considering within 3 seconds I have had 3 different opinions???

Comment: If you design your classes properly (or decorate them with `[XmlElement]` and other related attributes, the most efficient method I mentioned for converting XML to an object is using XmlSerializer.  But, it takes a bit to get the settings right.

Comment: At present, I have...

        public ViewResult Index()
    {
        string url = "......";
        var xml = XDocument.Load(url);

        return View(xml);
    }

What I would like to know now is... In the VIEW, normally EF puts something like:

@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Supplier>

But because Im not using a proper Database, what do I need to put here for model of XLinQ object?

Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: You can set the model to `XElement` if you want to use the root node, or a specific child node, as the model, or you can set the model to `List<XElement>` if you want to pass multiple nodes to the View.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]'.

Comment: This means you have a mismatch between the `@model` and what the controller is sending.  In other words, you are sending a single `XElement` from the controller, but you put `IEnumerable<XElement>` as the model. Use `@model XElement`.